# VersionOne Rest API not able to close Story

Tags: versionone

I have been in need to find API which we can fire to close different type of asset. Story is one of them.

I checked if Story can be close or deleted by API.

```
XML Response:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<Assets pageStart="0" pageSize="2147483647" total="1">-<Asset id="Story:2601366" href="/VersionOne/rest-1.v1/Data/Story/2601366"><Attribute name="Name">OAPHRP --> OAPFND 11/3-11/4</Attribute><Attribute name="IsDeletable">true</Attribute><Attribute name="CheckQuickClose">true</Attribute></Asset></Assets>
```

Based on this, I can delete/quick close story. So I fired below one.

- http://test-versionone.XXXXX.com/VersionOne/rest-1.oauth.v1/Data/Story/2601366?op=QuickClose
- http://test-versionone.XXXXX.com/VersionOne/rest-1.oauth.v1/Data/Story/2601366?op=Delete

Unfortunately, it didn't do anything. I tried to quick close and then I tried to close. I got response like below in both cases:

```
XMLResponse for Delete:
<xml>version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
-<Asset href="/VersionOne/rest-1.oauth.v1/Data/Story/2601366" id="Story:2601366"><Attribute name="AssetType">Story</Attribute><Attribute name="Benefits"/><Relation name="SplitFrom"/>-<Relation name="SecurityScope"><Asset href="/VersionOne/rest-1.oauth.v1/Data/Scope/2129369" idref="Scope:2129369"/></Relation>-<Relation name="Super"><Asset href="/VersionOne/rest-1.oauth.v1/Data/Epic/2814883" idref="Epic:2814883"/></Relation><Relation name="Team"/><Relation name="IdentifiedIn"/><Relation name="Parent"/><Relation name="Category"/><Relation name="Risk"/><Relation name="Customer"/><Relation name="Source"/><Relation name="Priority"/>-<Relation name="Status"><Asset href="/VersionOne/rest-1.oauth.v1/Data/StoryStatus/137" idref="StoryStatus:137"/></Relation>-<Relation name="Timebox"><Asset href="/VersionOne/rest-1.oauth.v1/Data/Timebox/2626276" idref="Timebox:2626276"/></Relation>-<Relation name="Scope"><Asset href="/VersionOne/rest-1.oauth.v1/Data/Scope/2129369" idref="Scope:2129369"/></Relation><Attribute name="Number">B-262556</Attribute><Attribute name="LastVersion"/><Attribute name="OriginalEstimate">1</Attribute><Attribute name="RequestedBy"/><Attribute name="Value"/><Attribute name="Order">-791022846</Attribute><Attribute name="Estimate">1</Attribute><Attribute name="Reference"/><Attribute name="ToDo"/><Attribute name="DetailEstimate"/><Attribute name="Description"/><Attribute name="Name">OAPHRP --> OAPFND 11/3-11/4</Attribute><Attribute name="AssetState">64</Attribute><Attribute name="SplitFrom.Name"/><Attribute name="SplitFrom.Number"/><Attribute name="SecurityScope.Name">Apps DBA M/S 1</Attribute><Attribute name="Super.Name">Cloning</Attribute><Attribute name="Super.Number">E-08725</Attribute><Attribute name="Team.Name"/><Attribute name="IdentifiedIn.Name"/><Attribute name="Parent.Name"/><Attribute name="Parent.Number"/><Attribute name="Category.Name"/><Attribute name="Risk.Name"/><Attribute name="Customer.Name"/><Attribute name="Customer.Nickname"/><Attribute name="Source.Name"/><Attribute name="Priority.Name"/><Attribute name="Status.Name">Accepted</Attribute><Attribute name="Timebox.Name">Sprint 24 (11/3 - 11/14)</Attribute><Attribute name="Scope.Name">Apps DBA M/S 1</Attribute><Attribute name="Ideas"/><Relation name="CompletedInBuildRuns"/><Attribute name="CompletedInBuildRuns.Name"/>-<Relation name="Owners"><Asset href="/VersionOne/rest-1.oauth.v1/Data/Member/1610365" idref="Member:1610365"/></Relation>-<Attribute name="Owners.Name"><Value>Brandon Hill</Value></Attribute>-<Attribute name="Owners.Nickname"><Value>Brandon Hill</Value></Attribute></Asset>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure how to flag it. _Unclear_, _off-topic/why-my-code-doesn't-work_, _off-topic/not-about-programming_ ...

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to enter those urls into a browser.  The deception here is that you are getting results from each url "op=keyword" at the end.  If you put op=GumbyDammit or anything, you will continue to get the the same results which is a query of a single Story with the identifier of 2601366.  Why? The API code that parses the

`http://test-versionone.XXXXX.com/VersionOne/rest-1.oauth.v1/Data/Story/2601366?op=Delete` pattern does not recognized this as a legal VersionOne query pattern, truncates the

`?op=Delete`

and only handles the subset

`http://test-versionone.XXXXX.com/VersionOne/rest-1.oauth.v1/Data/Story/2601366`

which a simple query. What you want to do is http POST an empty payload to `http://test-versionone.XXXXX.com/VersionOne/rest-1.oauth.v1/Data/Story/2601366?op=Delete`.
In summary, you can only read VersionOne data in the browser. All other operations must be posted to the Data endpoint.